# WebProxy WebClient Not Woriking in dot.net 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, webclient

I have a desktop application in one of my client site and, they are using a Proxy in their network. So I have some troubles and I need to authenticate with the proxy. I'm using following code to authenticate the proxy. My application in `.net 3.5`. I have tested the same code with `.net 4.0` and `.net 4.5`. so i figured that its working fine for above `.net 4`

```
            WebProxy webProxy = new WebProxy("url", true);
            webProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user name", "password");
            using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {

                webClient.Proxy = webProxy;

                byte[] Response = webClient.UploadValues("address", "POST", new NameValueCollection());
            }
```

Why this code isn't working in `.net 3.5`? is there any better solution? 
help me to get rid of this. because my desktop application must have `.net 3.5` for some reasons.

thanks in advance :)

Comment: any error you get ?

Comment: Yes. I got the following error. `webException the remote server returned an error:(407) proxy Authentication Required`

Comment: can you try by adding `<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
  </system.net>` in config or by adding ` webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;` in code

Comment: Have tried it earlier, not worked.

Comment: is you tried `Go to Tools -> Internet Options. Click on the Connections tab, then the LAN Settings button. Uncheck the "Automatically detect settings".`